# How to dedupe rows with mirrored values in 2 columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, duplicates

I was wondering if there is a way to dedupe a table that contains 2 columns that has mirrored values (so the expected table should be half the size).

For example, let's say I have the following as *Table 1*:

```
C1 || C2
========
A  ||  B
B  ||  A
```

Is there a deduping query where the result is only one of the above, such as:

```
C1 || C2
========
A  ||  B
```

I am thinking some kind of inner join is involved, but can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM mytable t1
  WHERE t1.c1 < t1.c2 AND t.c1 = t1.c2 AND t.c2 = t1.c1
)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1b2a92b0823907efd796b4c0dc0cc6c0)